# get and set Value of a Cell do not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have trouble with getting a Value from a Cell in my Spreadsheet. I found the getCell()-method in the documentation but it does not work. It always just gets "Range" instead of the Value. (it is a integer btw.)
And I don't find a setCell()-method ! o.O The Value is in the cell B:1
Thx for any help!!1 :)

```
var API_KEY           = "***",
    PROFILE_ID        = "****";
    GET_PLUS_ONES_URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"+PROFILE_ID+"?fields=plusOneCount&key="+API_KEY;
var currentPlusOnes = 0,
    lastPlusOnes    = 0,
    ss              = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function execute() {
  getCurrentPlusOnes();
  getLastPlusOnes();
  if ( currentPlusOnes !== getLastPlusOnes ) {
    setCurrentValue();
  }
}

function getCurrentPlusOnes() {
  currentPlusOnes = JSON.parse( UrlFetchApp.fetch( GET_PLUS_ONES_URI )).plusOneCount;
}

function getLastPlusOnes() {
  lastPlusOnes = ss.getRange("B1").getCell( 1, 1 ); // --> Allways just "Range" instead of the value
}

function setCurrentValue() {
  ss.getDataRange().setValue( currentPlusOnes );
}
```

Comment: lastPlusOnes = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

both `getRange()` and `getCell()` return a **Range** object. You need to get call `getValue()` or `getValues()` on a range to get the data out. In this case as your first `getRange("B1")` is only referencing a single cell, you don't need the `getCell(1,1)`

```
lastPlusOnes = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
```

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue%28%29)

for setting the same applies. a single value in a single cell would be:

```
Range.setValue( number | string )
```

or if you have a a bunch of rows and columns then first select the appropriate sized range and then use `setValues([][])`

Answer (score 3):

getCell() returns a Range object.. you need to add the .getValue() method to get the value of the cell in the range.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

Comment: Oh okay. My mistake. I am sorry :( :D