# Data binding in google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to write a google apps script that "binds" two cells together? For example, if a a cell in one sheet is edited, it will automatically update a matching cell in another sheet.

So if sheet1 had a value representing "money spent" in cell A1, and sheet2 had a value representing the same "money spent" in cell B4, I'd want to be able to change the value in sheet2.B4 or sheet1.A1, and both of the cells will always be up to date.

I'm having trouble determining how to create a trigger that could perform this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a trigger that runs a function when a cell in the Sheet is edited:

[SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit())

Then the script would need to find the cell that was edited, get the value, and put the value into the new cell.

You could use `getRange()`:

[getRange(row, column) of the Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

See this question also:

[StackOverflow get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520642/get-and-set-value-of-a-cell-do-not-work)