# Google Sheets change one cell from another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, cell

In Google sheets, I have a formula that shows data from the Tab A to Tab B based on some criteria because the main page is very difficult to read.

How can I change what's on the Tab A from Tab B? In other words, I want users to see only what's in Tab B and be able to make changes as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data binding in google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767721/data-binding-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: This can be put on hold under the official reason of "Needs Focus".

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it possible to change what's on the Tab A from Tab B.**

Answer:**Yes**

**Example:** Cell A1 in TabA contains =TabB!A1

**Explanation:** Values you put in TabB cell A1 will also be displayed in TabA Cell A1.

> **Is it better to copy the data rather than show it using a formula?**

This is not a good question for us because it depends upon our opinion.

So the answer is **Yes** and **No**.

> **Would this require some kind of Macro?**

You probably already know the answer to that question because one of your tags is JavaScript and another is Google Apps Script.

**Final Question Paraphrased:**

> **Can you write this script for me because I'm not smart enough to figure it on my own?**

**Answer:**

Most of us can. Some of us will and some of us won't. And I suspect that you are in fact smart enough to figure it out on your own.  It will take a little time and a little effort on your part.  The Google Apps Script documentation is very good and there are many sources of learning online for JavaScript which is the core of Google Apps Script.

In any case you're going to have to be more specific about what you want.  There are a lot of resources on this site to help you ask better questions. I recommend that you seek them out.